# $\text{Max}\big(\text{Sub}(\text{Sym}(\omega))\setminus \{\text{Sym}(\omega)\}\big)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, order-theory, posets

If $G$ is any group, then by $\text{Sub}(G)$ we denote the collection of all subgroups, ordered by $\subseteq$. If $(P,\leq)$ is a [partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) we let $\text{Max}(P)$ and the set of maximal elements.

Let $\frak{S}$ be the group of all bijections $f:\omega\to\omega$ together with composition.

Is there a member of $\text{Sub}(\frak{S}) \setminus \{\frak{S}\}$ that is not contained in some member of $\text{Max}\big(\text{Sub}(\frak{S})\setminus \{\frak{S}\}\big)$?

Comment: @andreasthom sorry got the question totally wrong -- please see the revised one

Comment: Are you asking whether there's an element of $P$ which is not upper bounded by a maximal element of $P$, where $P$ is some poset of subgroups?

Comment: Jalex: My guess is that he is asking if ``there's an element of P which is not upper bounded by a maximal element of P, where P is THE poset of subgroups''.

Comment: That's correct @peterkomjath. I want P to be the poset of proper subgroups --  that is, all the subgroups of $\text{Sym}(\omega)$ except $\text{Sym}(\omega)$ itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was written by Andreas Thom in his comment, Google gives an extensive literature on this subject. For example, look at the papers
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-011-2080-7_18
or https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/jlms/s2-42.1.85
of Macpherson and his coauthors.

The question posed by Dominic van der Zypen was considered by [Baumgartner, Shelah and Thomas](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093634559) who constructed a consistent example of a proper subgroup of $Sym(\omega)$ that is not contained in a proper maximal subgroup of $Sym(\omega)$.